# Reweighting hazard ratios

Tags: hazard, ratio

Assume I have two populations (pop 1 and pop 2). I also have three treatments (A, B, C).

In population 1, I have $HR_{A vs B}$

In population 2, I have $HR_{A vs B}$ and $HR_{C vs B}$

When I want to calculate the $HR_{C vs B}$ in population 1, I can use the ratio of the $HR_{A vs B}$ in pop 1 and pop 2 to reweight. Should this be done on the HR itself or on the log scale?

E.g.
Option 1: $HR_{Pop 1 - C vs B}$ = $HR_{Pop 2 - C vs B} * (HR_{Pop 1 - A vs B} / HR_{Pop 2 - A vs B})$

Option 2: $HR_{Pop 1 - C vs B}$ = $\exp(\ln(HR_{Pop 2 - C vs B}) * (\ln (HR_{Pop 1 - A vs B}) / \ln(HR_{Pop 2 - A vs B}))$

Comment: How exactly is a hazard ratio used to reweight a hazard ratio? Weights are typically either (an inverse of) frequency or a probability, but a HR is neither and (more importantly) it is a constant.

Comment: Since the HR of A vs B is different in populations 1 and 2, the reweighting would be more a population adjustment. Assuming shared effect modification between treatments A and C, one would expect to see a different HR of C vs B in population 1 and 2 as well.

Comment: It might help to run a little R script to show what you're trying to do. First off, your populations are probably samples, actually. If you obtained an HR of 0.5 in sample 1, and reran an analysis in sample 2 and weighted each subject by 0.5 it would have no impact whatsoever on the analysis or inference.